# Intel XDK : where is the PERSISENT filesystem root folder in Emulate mode ?

Tags: fileapi, intel-xdk

I would like to test my application's behaviour in handling files from its Persistent storage. I succeed to retrieve the LocalFileSystem.PERSISENT (with the File API) which gives me root = "\", containing neither files nor folders.
I would like to place ther manually some files (I'm in an early development stage) in order to test my app in the emulate mode.

But In don't find where is this root folder on my PC.

Can anyone help me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but try looking under your `AppData\Local\XDK` folder.  One suggestion is `\Users\idsid\AppData\Local\XDK\File System\000\p` for the persistent file system and `\Users\idsid\AppData\Local\XDK\File System\000\t` for the temporary file system, but I haven't verified that myself.

Be aware, though, the LocalFileSystem API doesn't seem to be catching on, according to [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/):

> In April 2014, it was announced on public-webapps that the Filesystem API spec should be considered dead. Other browsers have showed little interest in implementing it.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you may want to look into [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage) or the [Cordova File API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. First of all, you're right. This the right place. But XDK does not store the files as they are store through the API. My file "olala.txt" became "000001". There is probably somewhere a mapping file/db. This is unusable for my tests. By the way, I'm using the Cordova default file API.